# chrome failed to load spotfire link

Tags: html, google-chrome, spotfire, tibco

I am currently displaying the spotfire web player link via simple html call and it is working fine when using the **Mozilla Firefox** browser but if trying to load on **Chrome** browser it fails to load and here is the error on the web player display on the link:

```
Failed to load application
Could not load localized labels
Could not load configuration
```

And here is the simple html call:

```
<object data="http://myHost/spotfire/wp/render" type="text/html" style="width:100%; height:1000px;">
        Alternative Content
    </object>
```

Any suggestion/comments TIA

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it has to do with Chrome's update to block cross-site scripting.

In your console do you get any errors describing Cross-site/samesite=none errors thrown?

I had a similar issue with Chrome when using Spotfires Javascript API and it only occurred in Chrome. Here is a [Post](https://community.tibco.com/questions/spotfire-javascript-api-cross-sitesamesite-cookies) regarding it.

The overall fix was an update to the Spotfire Server setting of [SameSite](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/10.3.8/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-6E29E75E-FCC9-4CF3-BBAB-2033030AAC09.html).

Comment: appreciate your suggestion do you have a sample steps or instruction on how to disable that?

Comment: This link has the most detailed steps : https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-Spotfire-JavaScript-Mashup-API-stops-working-in-Chrome-due-to-SameSite-problem?_ga=2.256872136.2144647963.1601308096-1792525578.1584378075

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a registry key.  I have a blog post on this.
https://datashoptalk.com/use-chrome-web-player/